# How to fix: Attribute xmlns:gco redefined

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I'm using XSLT to update some old XML metadata and I realized that the target output has the following namespace:

```
xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0"
```

the old metadata has the following namespace:

```
xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco
```

If I put both in the header of the XSLT I got the error 
*Attribute xmlns:gco redefined*

I tried to delete one of them but the XSLT is not able to extract the correct value and I got empty string:

```
xsltApplySequenceConstructor: copy node identificationInfo
xsltApplySequenceConstructor: copy node MD_DataIdentification
xsltApplySequenceConstructor: copy node citation
xsltApplySequenceConstructor: copy node CI_Citation
xsltApplySequenceConstructor: copy node title
xsltApplySequenceConstructor: copy node CharacterString
xsltValueOf: select //gmd:identificationInfo/gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:citation/gmd:CI_Citation/gmd:title/gco:CharacterString
xsltValueOf: result ''
```

This is a part of  the XML input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gmi:MI_Metadata xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:safe="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0" xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" xmlns:s1="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0/sentinel-1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s1sar="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0/sentinel-1/sar" xmlns:gmi="http://sdi.eurac.edu/metadata/iso19139-2/schema/gmi" xmlns:s1sarl1="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0/sentinel-1/sar/level-1" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:s1sarl2="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0/sentinel-1/sar/level-2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" gco:isoType="gmd:MD_Metadata" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sdi.eurac.edu/metadata/iso19139-2/schema/gmi http://sdi.eurac.edu/metadata/iso19139-2/schema/gmi/gmi.xsd">
<gmd:identificationInfo>
        <gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
            <gmd:citation>
                <gmd:CI_Citation>
                    <gmd:title xsi:type="gmd:PT_FreeText_PropertyType">
                        <gco:CharacterString>TITLE_1</gco:CharacterString>
                    </gmd:title>
                    <gmd:alternateTitle>
                        <gco:CharacterString>TITLE_2</gco:CharacterString>
                    </gmd:alternateTitle>   
                </gmd:CI_Citation>      
            </gmd:citation>         
        </gmd:MD_DataIdentification>            
</gmd:identificationInfo>
</gmi:MI_Metadata>
```

and the following is the XSL file I'm using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
<mdb:MD_Metadata xmlns:mri="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mri/1.0"
                 xmlns:mrl="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrl/2.0"
                 xmlns:mas="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mas/1.0"
                 xmlns:mrs="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrs/1.0"
                 xmlns:mda="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mda/1.0"
                 xmlns:mrd="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrd/1.0"
                 xmlns:mdt="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdt/2.0"
                 xmlns:mco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mco/1.0"
                 xmlns:mex="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mex/1.0"
                 xmlns:msr="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/msr/2.0"
                 xmlns:mds="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mds/2.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:gfc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19110/gfc/1.1"
                 xmlns:mmi="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mmi/1.0"
                 xmlns:srv="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/srv/2.1"
                 xmlns:lan="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0"
                 xmlns:mac="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mac/2.0"
                 xmlns:gcx="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gcx/1.0"
                 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                 xmlns:mrc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrc/2.0"
                 xmlns:gex="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gex/1.0"
                 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
                 xmlns:mdb="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdb/2.0"
                 xmlns:cit="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/2.0"
                 xmlns:cat="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cat/1.0"
                 xmlns:mcc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"
                 xmlns:mdq="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19157/-2/mdq/1.0"
                 xmlns:mpc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mpc/1.0"
                 xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
                 xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0"
                 xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
                 >
    <mdb:identificationInfo>
      <mri:MD_DataIdentification>
         <mri:citation>
            <cit:CI_Citation>
               <cit:title>
                  <gco:CharacterString>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//gmd:identificationInfo/gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:citation/gmd:CI_Citation/gmd:title/gco:CharacterString"/>
                  </gco:CharacterString>
               </cit:title>
               <cit:alternateTitle>
                  <gco:CharacterString>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//gmd:identificationInfo/gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:citation/gmd:CI_Citation/gmd:alternatetitle/gco:CharacterString"/>
                  </gco:CharacterString>
               </cit:alternateTitle>
            </cit:CI_Citation>
        </mri:citation>
        </mri:MD_DataIdentification>
    </mdb:identificationInfo>
</mdb:MD_Metadata>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It has the two namespaces defined.

The desired output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mdb:MD_Metadata xmlns:mri="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mri/1.0"
                 xmlns:mrl="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrl/2.0"
                 xmlns:mas="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mas/1.0"
                 xmlns:mrs="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrs/1.0"
                 xmlns:mda="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mda/1.0"
                 xmlns:mrd="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrd/1.0"
                 xmlns:mdt="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdt/2.0"
                 xmlns:mco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mco/1.0"
                 xmlns:mex="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mex/1.0"
                 xmlns:msr="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/msr/2.0"
                 xmlns:mds="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mds/2.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:gfc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19110/gfc/1.1"
                 xmlns:mmi="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mmi/1.0"
                 xmlns:srv="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/srv/2.1"
                 xmlns:lan="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0"
                 xmlns:mac="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mac/2.0"
                 xmlns:gcx="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gcx/1.0"
                 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                 xmlns:mrc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrc/2.0"
                 xmlns:gex="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gex/1.0"
                 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
                 xmlns:mdb="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdb/2.0"
                 xmlns:cit="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/2.0"
                 xmlns:cat="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cat/1.0"
                 xmlns:mcc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"
                 xmlns:mdq="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19157/-2/mdq/1.0"
                 xmlns:mpc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mpc/1.0"
                 xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
                 xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0">                 
    <mdb:identificationInfo>
        <mri:MD_DataIdentification>
            <mri:citation>
                <cit:CI_Citation>
                <cit:title>
                  <gco:CharacterString>TITLE_1</gco:CharacterString>
                </cit:title>
               <cit:alternateTitle>
                  <gco:CharacterString>TITLE_2</gco:CharacterString>
               </cit:alternateTitle>
                </cit:CI_Citation>
            </mri:citation>
        </mri:MD_DataIdentification>
    </mdb:identificationInfo>
</mdb:MD_Metadata>
```

Is there a way to solve this conflict and use both of them? Or do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another prefix for the "old" namespace. Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<gco:input xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">123</gco:input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:old="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0"
exclude-result-prefixes="old">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <gco:output>
        <xsl:value-of select="old:input"/>
    </gco:output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gco:output xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0">123</gco:output>
```

Comment: I added the input XML file with the XSL I'm using and the desired output

Comment: Can't you make your own adaptation?